# What are the exit codes of command PING?

Tags: bash, batch-file

I want to know which exit codes (or errorlevel numbers) are returned by command `ping` to the parent process like `cmd.exe` on using this command in a Windows batch file or `bash` on using `ping` in a bash shell script in the following use cases?

1. When all packets are sent and received.
2. When no packets are received.
3. Request timed out.
4. Other conditions

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, `ping` errorlevel is 0 unless the target host does not exist, then it is 1. There are no other errorlevels.

If you're trying to determine if `ping` was successful, check the output for the string `TTL`.

```
REM Use the full path for system tools in case the user makes bad script-naming decisions
set "ping=%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe"
set "find=%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe"

%ping% %url% | %find% "TTL" >nul
if "%errorlevel%"=="0" (
    echo Ping was successful
) else (
    echo Ping was not successful
)
```

---

On Linux hosts, `ping` has an errorlevel of 0 on success, 1 if the host is unreachable, 2 if the target host does not exist.

Comment: this is not correct answer, ping.exe set errorlevel to 0 if program report "TTL expired in transit" for example.

Comment: @user2956477 - as I stated in my answer, Windows `ping` sets errorlevel to 1 if the target host does not exist and 0 in literally every other situation, so your scenario and my information match.

Comment: Hint for readers: It is better to use `if not errorlevel 1` (less than 1) instead of `if "%errorlevel%"=="0"` as that works also in a command block and is evaluated much faster by the Windows command processor although no user will ever notice the difference (just the CPU). `ping.exe` never exits with a negative value which no executable should do ever as recommended for all operating systems.

Comment: Ehh, some people likely find the `if errorlevel number` syntax to be somewhat unintuitive, and `!errorlevel!` is a perfectly valid syntax that lets you use the exact value rather than `GEQ` the value.